# Using BitSet properly to replace int based flag. Is it possible?

Tags: java, performance, bit, bitset

I am getting an int from a data source that serves as a flag. Example:

```
private static final int EMPLOYEE   =     0x00000001;  
private static final int IT         =     0x00000002;  
private static final int MARKETING  =     0x00000004;  
private static final int DATA        =    0x00000008;  
private static final int DBAs = IT | DATA;  
private static final int DATA_REPORTERS = MARKETING | DATA;  

private static boolean isDba(int flag){
  return (flag & DBAs) == flag;
}

private static boolean isInIT(int flag) {
  return (flag & IT) == flag;
}

class Employee {
  private int role;  
  private final String name;    
  //etc 
}  

employee = fetchEmployee()
if(isDba(employee.role)){
   System.out.println("Is a DBA");
}
```

This seems to work ok but I also was looking into the `EnumSet` in case I can simplify the code a bit bit it does not seem to me that it does.
E.g I would need to have:

```
private static final int EMPLOYEE   =     1;  // bit 1
private static final int IT         =     2;  // bit 2
private static final int MARKETING  =     3;  // bit 3
private static final int DATA        =    4;  // bit 4
```

Which are the individual bits to set but I can figure out how the following can be done:

```
private static final int DBAs = IT | DATA;  
private static final int DATA_REPORTERS = MARKETING | DATA;
```

with `BitSet`

So how would the above be implemented properly with a `BitSet` (assuming that `BitSet` is the right choice since I don't need to do any updates on the bitset just check the flags)

Comment: I think using bit masks is fine as it is. Alternatively, create a class with 4 boolean fields. Why do you want to use `BitSet`?

Comment: why have you tagged the question with performance?

Comment: @Sweeper: That would mean X flags for each type (I don't have only 4)

Comment: @Jocke: Because I think performance wise my approach should be better than other alternatives but would like to hear more options

Comment: then why don't you measure it (hard I know), or compile it and read the bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an EnumSet is preferable to a BitSet, especially if you only need readOnly access.

```
enum EmployeeRole {
  EMPLOYEE, IT, MARKETING, DATA
}

EnumSet<EmployeeRole> DBAs = EnumSet.of(IT, DATA);
EnumSet<EmployeeRole> DATA_REPORTERS = EnumSet.of(MARKETING, DATA);

class Employee {
  EnumSet<EmployeeRole> roles;

  boolean isDba(){
     for(EmployeeRole role: roles){
       if(DBAs.contains(role){
         return true;
       }
     }
     return false;
  }
}
```

But if you store your flags in a database as a single field in the database, you need a conversion, e.g. using good old apache commons-lang [EnumUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html)

```
//write
long rolesAsLong = EnumUtils.generateBitVector(EmployeeRole.class, employee.getRoles())
//read
employee.setRoles(EnumUtils.processBitVector(EmployeeRole.class, rolesAsLong));
```

Or you can write a custom hibernate UserType for that. These might inspire you: https://github.com/search?q=EnumSetUserType&type=Code

Comment: I like the code snippet you provided. It is very clean. I am not really sure that performance wise it is better especially if I need to depend to a library. My use case is to get the flags from a network source (which means an int or long over the wire), have a largish number of such objects having that `role` and save them in a local DB cache. It seems that `EnumSet` adds extra overhead and extra dependencies since I can just check the flags directly as pasted in the post. What are your thoughts? May be I am missing out something?

Comment: So if I get this `EnumUtils.processBitVector(EmployeeRole.class, rolesAsLong)` how would that be generated in the first place? I mean the `rolesAsLong`? Is it java specific?

Comment: There's extra overhead in the conversion, that's true. The methods on EnumSet itself are however quite optimised, so the .contains() should be as fast as your own bit masks.

If performance is an issue, and the conversion overhead would have an impact on that, I think I would also stick with the bitmask approach as you did.

Comment: Besides the performance, is that approach Java specific? I mean from the network source how would they have the `rolesAsLong` to send it over the wire if they don't have the code base for `EmployeeRole`?

Comment: I guess EnumUtils uses the normal bitmasking methods, so the rolesAsLong is not java-specific. It is 64 bits, so it allows to set 64 different flags. And I guess it uses the ordinals of the enum, so in this case EMPLOYEE is first bit, IT is second bit etc. You have to do some tests to be sure.

Comment: I will check but I am confused now. Because from the doc I don't see any restriction to use only 64 enum values which seems to be needed for the `EnumUtils` to work https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

Comment: It's the encoding that won't work for more than 64 bits, unless you use multiple longs: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#generateBitVector-java.lang.Class-E...-